# How to fix 'in find_element_by_id return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)' error in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm developing a webscraper via Selenium and Python. When I run it from the command prompt by entering the code per line, it runs fine. But when I run it via the `python [program name]` method, it returns this error:

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR3R3.png)

Is my selenium version incompatible?
Thanks :)

Here's my code:

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C://Users/user1/Portable Python 3.7.0 x64/App/Python/Lib/site-packages/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://tweeterid.com/')
bar = browser.find_element_by_name('twitter')
bar.send_keys('865102744809381888')
bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

out = browser.find_element_by_id('0')
temp = out.text

data = temp.split('=>') #split string into a list

list = []

list.append(data[1])

browser.refresh()`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is when you execute the code using python  it does not wait for the enter key and finds the find_element_by_id('0') 
Add `time.sleep(5)` after `bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

I hope this will solve your problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://tweeterid.com/')
bar = browser.find_element_by_name('twitter')
bar.send_keys('865102744809381888')
bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)

out = browser.find_element_by_id('0')
temp = out.text

data = temp.split('=>') #split string into a list

list = []

list.append(data[1])
```